# Unexpected manual page break behavior. Why is excel adding extra page breaks / breaking on the wrong row?

Tags: excel, vba, page-break

I am automating some paperwork creation in the office. In one sheet I have the users enter the data that needs to be selectively copied to certain other worksheets that will the be printed out for use on the production floor. **Currently I have a problem with the formatting of my "Ship" sheet.** The first sheet is empty. It is expected that the user will use this page to summarize the packing list by handwriting each unique box, bundle, and pallet listed under "Container Type & Number" from the line items on the "Prep" sheet, which are on page 2(+).

After running the macro, **it appears that Excel is adding an additional page break immediately after each row I manually set page breaks for.** When I am in "Page Layout" view and switch to the "Ship" worksheet it appears to be 5 pages long for the current example data I am using. However, the data should only require 2 pages in addition to the cover sheet for a grand total of 3 pages. Pages 2 and 4 appear to only have one row and quickly jumps to the next page when scrolling. Also, I just noticed that the header I use for pages 2+ only appears above the single-row page 2 and the rest of "page 2" that shows up on page 3. The header does not appear at all for pages 4 and 5. What makes this problem hard to capture is that print preview shows only 3 total pages, and the rows that should have the manual page break before them are shifted to appear as the last row of the preceding page.

I have tried writing this macro three slightly different ways:
1. Sheet.Rows(#).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
2. Sheet.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Sheet.Rows(#)
3. Sheet.HPageBreaks(#).Location = Sheet.Range("A" & #)

**NOTE: I found this article from Microsoft after experiencing repeat "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" errors with option (3), and re-coded that option accordingly** https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/210663/you-receive-a-subscript-out-of-range-error-message-when-you-use-hpageb

The weirdest part is that if I step into option (3) line-by-line in debug mode, the macro actually formats the page correctly...

## Here is the relevant code:

```
Option Explicit

'Public sSht As Worksheet
'Public sDatRng As Range, pDatRng As Range, pCopyRng As Range
'Public sCopyRow As Long, pCopyRow As Long
'Public sNumRows As Long, sHeadFootRows As Long, pNumRows As Long, pHeadFootRows As Long

Sub formatShipV1(numPgs As Long)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim currcell As Range

    Application.PrintCommunication = False

    With sSht
        .Cells.PageBreak = xlPageBreakNone

        With .PageSetup
            .Zoom = False
            .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
            .Orientation = xlPortrait
            .PrintArea = sSht.Range("A1:J" & ((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (numPgs * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)))).Address
            .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.2)
            .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.2)
            .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.6)
            .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.6)
            .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
            .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = numPgs + 1
            .CenterHorizontally = True
            .CenterVertically = False
        End With

        For i = 0 To (numPgs - 1)
            .Rows((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (i * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)) + 1).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual

            .Rows((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (i * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)) + 1).RowHeight = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
            .Rows((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (i * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)) + 2).RowHeight = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .Rows((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (i * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)) + 3).RowHeight = Application.InchesToPoints(0.19)
            .Rows((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (i * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)) + 4).RowHeight = Application.InchesToPoints(0.57)

            Set rng = sSht.Range(Cells(((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (i * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)) + 5), 1).Address & ":" & Cells(((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (i * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)) + 26), 10).Address)
            rng.RowHeight = Application.InchesToPoints(0.38)

            .Rows((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (i * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)) + 27).RowHeight = Application.InchesToPoints(0.23)
        Next
    End With

    Application.PrintCommunication = True
End Sub

Sub formatShipV2(numPgs As Long)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim currcell As Range

    Application.PrintCommunication = False

    With sSht
        .ResetAllPageBreaks

        With .PageSetup
            .Zoom = False
            .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
            .Orientation = xlPortrait
            .PrintArea = sSht.Range("A1:J" & ((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (numPgs * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)))).Address
            .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.2)
            .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.2)
            .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.6)
            .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.6)
            .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
            .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = numPgs + 1
            .CenterHorizontally = True
            .CenterVertically = False
        End With

        For i = 0 To (numPgs - 1)
            .HPageBreaks.Add Before:=sSht.Rows(((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (i * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)) + 1))

            .Rows((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (i * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)) + 1).RowHeight = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
            .Rows((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (i * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)) + 2).RowHeight = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .Rows((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (i * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)) + 3).RowHeight = Application.InchesToPoints(0.19)
            .Rows((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (i * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)) + 4).RowHeight = Application.InchesToPoints(0.57)

            Set rng = sSht.Range(Cells(((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (i * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)) + 5), 1).Address & ":" & Cells(((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (i * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)) + 26), 10).Address)
            rng.RowHeight = Application.InchesToPoints(0.38)

            .Rows((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (i * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)) + 27).RowHeight = Application.InchesToPoints(0.23)
        Next
    End With

    Application.PrintCommunication = True
End Sub

Sub formatShipV3(numPgs As Long)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim currcell As Range

    Call endOptimize
    Set currcell = ActiveCell
    Range("IV65536").Select

    Application.PrintCommunication = False

    With sSht
        .Activate
        ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
        .ResetAllPageBreaks

        With .PageSetup
            .Zoom = False
            .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
            .Orientation = xlPortrait
            .PrintArea = sSht.Range("A1:J" & ((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (numPgs * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)))).Address
            .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.2)
            .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.2)
            .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.6)
            .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.6)
            .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
            .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = numPgs + 1
            .CenterHorizontally = True
            .CenterVertically = False
        End With

        For i = 0 To (numPgs - 1)
            Set .HPageBreaks(i + 1).Location = sSht.Range("A" & ((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (i * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)) + 1))
            DoEvents

            .Rows((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (i * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)) + 1).RowHeight = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
            .Rows((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (i * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)) + 2).RowHeight = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .Rows((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (i * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)) + 3).RowHeight = Application.InchesToPoints(0.19)
            .Rows((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (i * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)) + 4).RowHeight = Application.InchesToPoints(0.57)

            Set rng = sSht.Range(Cells(((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (i * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)) + 5), 1).Address & ":" & Cells(((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (i * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)) + 26), 10).Address)
            rng.RowHeight = Application.InchesToPoints(0.38)

            .Rows((sNumRows + sHeadFootRows) + (i * (pNumRows + pHeadFootRows)) + 27).RowHeight = Application.InchesToPoints(0.23)
        Next

        ActiveWindow.View = xlPageLayoutView

    End With

    Application.PrintCommunication = True

    sSht.Activate
    sSht.Range(currcell.Address).Select
    Call startOptimize
End Sub

Sub startOptimize()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
End Sub

Sub endOptimize()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True
End Sub

'Sub runMacro()
'    Call startOptimize
'    ...
'    Dim sNumSht As Long
'    ...
'    Other variable declarations
'    ...
'    Set sSht = datBk.Worksheets("Ship")
'    Set sDatRng = sSht.Range("B6:J27")
'    Set pDatRng = sSht.Range("B32:J53")
'    Set pCopyRng = sSht.Range("A28:J54")
'    sNumRows = 22
'    sHeadFootRows = 5
'    pCopyRow = 55
'    pNumRows = 22
'    pHeadFootRows = 5
'    ...
'    Other variable initializations
'    ...
'    Code to calculate what data to copy to the "Ship" sheet, and how many pages "sNumSht" should equal
'    ...
'    Call formatShipV1((sNumSht + 1))
'    '-OR-
'    Call formatShipV2((sNumSht + 1))
'    '-OR-
'    Call formatShipV3((sNumSht + 1))
'    ...
'    Code to copy previously determined data to ship sheet
'    ...
'    Code to execute the rest of the macro
'    ...
'    Call endOptimize
'End Sub
```

### Expected formatting of "Ship" sheet [produced via "stepping into" option (3)]:

[image: Correct Ship sheet formatting]

### Actual formatting of "Ship" sheet (options 1-3 when run normally):

-As displayed in Excel (only showing page 1-3 out of 5):
[image: Incorrect Ship sheet formatting, as displayed]

-As printed to PDF via Excel's Print Preview:
[image: Incorrect Ship sheet formatting, as printed]

Comment: In case the links at the end don't automatically work, here is the actual dropbox url to the correct formatting <https://www.dropbox.com/s/2tehhxqc543x30b/2019_0213-Correct_Ship_Sheet_Formatting.pdf?dl=0>, the incorrect formatting as displayed in Excel <https://www.dropbox.com/s/0n29o3mv2czj5ip/2019_0213-Incorrect_Ship_Sheet_Formatting-As_Displayed.PNG?dl=0>, and the incorrect formatting when printed to PDF <https://www.dropbox.com/s/ul4iudcip5nkyna/2019_0213-Incorrect_Ship_Sheet_Formatting-As_Printed.pdf?dl=0>

Comment: This answer explains, when/why Excel sets page breaks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54259484/10908769

Comment: @Asger Is that only when manually setting page break by hand in the "Page Break Preview" view? I'm not understanding why that would add an additional page break above each page break when (1) I'm moving the page break down to squish more rows onto the page like you said, and (2) one of my methods specifically refers to the index of each page break starting with `sSht.HPageBreaks(1).Location = sSht.Range("A28")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause for many nearby breaks:
They may have been entered during intensive testing.

Background on the error:

- You tried to reset all page breaks first by `Worksheet.Cells.PageBreak = xlPageBreakNone`.
  That didn't work, so all your manual test breaks are still there.
- If you define `PageSetup.Zoom = False` and `PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 3`,
  then additional manual page breaks don't become effective.
  ***Manual breaks can still be set, but are neither effective nor visible.***

---

Solution 1: If ...

- a fit of the print area to the page width is generally okay
- any of your pages has to have *less* count rows than automatic scaling
- and none of your pages has to have *more* rows than automatic scaling

... then set your manual horizontal page breaks as follows:

1. Reset all page breaks first by `Worksheet.ResetAllPageBreaks`
2. Then define the automatic part of your page breaks by
   `PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1`
   `Pagesetup.FitToPagesTall = False`
   Do not set the Zoom. It is set to False by above lines.
3. Place a manual horizontal page break at the end of each page, that should contain less rows than automatically set. Do that from top to bottom.

---

Solution 2: If any of your pages needs *more rows* than above, then do it like this:

1. Reset all page breaks first by `Worksheet.ResetAllPageBreaks`
2. Define an appropriate zoom level, which suits for the page with many rows, e. g.
   `PageSetup.Zoom = 80`
   `PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = False`
   `PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = False`
3. Place manual horizontal page breaks to shorten pages as needed. Do that from the beginning to the end of your document.

---

Setting a manual horizontal page break can be done by either of these methods:

- `Worksheet.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=ws.Rows(10)`
- `Worksheet.Rows(10).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual`

The first method is [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54917079/10908769) than the second.

---

`Worksheet.HPageBreaks.Count` will show the number of horizontal page breaks in the print area including automatic breaks. Following will not "convert" the first automatic page break. It just moves the first manual break, if there is at least one:

- `Set Worksheet.HPageBreaks(1).Location = ws.Rows(20)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will try modifying all of the variants to use `Worksheet.ResetAllPageBreaks`. For your point about setting the print scale, do you mean I should be setting `.FitToPagesTall = Automatic` before adding the manual page breaks to get the result I am hoping for?

Also, do you know of any more detailed resources about the inner mechanics of creating page breaks that might point towards where to add timers / `DoEvents`? I'm just frustrated because I feel like it has to be a bug at this point...especially if you read that crap in their 'workaround' article...

Comment: I apologize for the delay. Setting `PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = False` appears to have done the trick! Also, just to clarify I used the `Worksheet.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=sSht.Rows(10)` method. You meant for your two bullet points to set a horizontal page break to be either / or, not use both together. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, use only one of the two methods. I'll clarify it in my answer.