# Fastest way to insert multiple page breaks in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to insert multiple page breaks into a document (a few hundred) and am trying to find the fastest way. I know with most sheet operations in excel it is fastest to batch them as an array or range and then perform them all at once. But with page breaks I can't see a way around performing individually within a loop.
The code below works but is slow

```
 With shtBagCheckList
    .Cells.PageBreak = xlPageBreakNone
    For i = 13 To lngArrayRows Step 12
        .Cells(i, 1).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual

    Next i
End With
```

A technique I sometimes use to apply formatting is to combine all the ranges that require the same formatting into one range and then apply the formatting to the combined range. Like this:

```
Set rngToBold = Union(rngToBold, Rng2) 'etc in a loop
rngToBold.Font.Bold = True
```

But doing that with page breaks, the break is only applied to the first element in the range. For example doing the below only create a page break at row 12, none at 24

```
set rng = range("A12", "A24")
rng.PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
```

What is the fastest way to add many page breaks into a sheet?

**Update**
Here are the results I got using tips from user11121185 and Tim Williams.
It turns out using HpageBreaks.add is way faster

```
1 rng.Page Break, calculation on: 20.594 (45%)  
2 rng.Page Break,  calculation off: 13.219 (29%)  
3 rng.Page Break, calculation off, display breaks off: 11.922 (26%)  
4 hbreaks.add,calculation on: 0.018 (0%)  
5 hbreaks.add, calculation off : 0.203 (0%)  
6 hbreaks.add, calculation off, display page breaks off: 0.312 (1%)  
Total Time: 46.267
```

(calculation off means automatic calculation and screen updating off)

Usage is like this:

```
sheet.HPageBreaks.Add sheet.range("A10")
```

Or:

```
 With shtBagCheckList
    .Cells.PageBreak = xlPageBreakNone
    For i = 13 To lngArrayRows Step 12
        .HPageBreaks.Add .Cells(i, 1)

    Next i
 End With
```

Comment: AFAIK, you can only insert a single manual page break at one time. If you are experiencing noticeable delays, I suspect that it would be due to automated repagination after every insertion but I know of no way to suspend automated pagination. Have you experimented with .Sheet.HPageBreaks.Add vs. rng.PageBreak?

Comment: Try turning off `.DisplayPageBreaks` before adding the page breaks.  Setting `Application.Screenupdating = False` may also help.

Comment: This is maybe farfetched but when doing a pagebreak, Excel also connects to the default printer. If This is a network printer for instance then of could be slower to create the pagebreak.

Comment: @user11121185 good tip, HpageBreaks.add is way faster, you may want to submit as answer. Here are the results  

1 rng.Page Break, calculation on: 20.594 (45%)  
2 rng.Page Break,  calculation off: 13.219 (29%)  
3 rng.Page Break, calculation off, display breaks off: 11.922 (26%)  
4 hbreaks.add, calculation on: 0.018 (0%)  
5 hbreaks.add, calculation off : 0.203 (0%)  
6 hbreaks.add, calculation off, display page breaks off: 0.312 (1%)  
Total Time: 46.267